# given a connected graph, how many pairs of distinct edges have a common vertex? need another method!

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Need an answer, been stuck for years! I have one method I think, which is summing over the vertices in the graph using the degree of a given vertex choose 2; but I still am missing the 2nd method.
Any help Appreciated,
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you summed over the vertices, why not sum over the edges then?

For each endpoint of the edge, count the degree minus 1.

Sum, divide by two to address double counting.

Comment: of course! thanks mate nice work